# Database options in VBA

Tags: vb.net

I use Visual Studios 2013 Ultimate RC. And i am trying to make an application that Creates a database(without needing Access or an SQL server) in the installation file and Stores all data there. I would use a basic 5 column design or something of the sort. Is there any kind of options? or if i distribute my program will everyone need to have MS Access? Any Help would be wonderful.

Comment: Is this data read-only, or read/write? Fixed, or variable? Windows, or any OS?

Comment: If the data is not sensitive, CSV would be easy to manage

Comment: Well I Have a few options so yet another Question I guess. I want the database fields to be a default that I decide but the user populates the fields with lets say, "First Name", "Last Name", "Phone Number", "Email", and "Cell Phone Carrier".

Comment: Cell Phone Carrier is a Variable too seeing it is a list of the Major carries then it assigns the carriers Email ending so you can Email Cell phone numbers from the program using Gmail and For free.

Comment: Is this app web based?

Comment: You can distribute a blank DB with the correct schema so your app can be assured that the columns exist in tables named what your app expects. Users would not have to have Access to run your app. You did not say HOW `the user populates the fields with lets say...`.  If you do not include an Add/Change/Delete data entry method in your app, then they **would** have to have Access installed to Add/Change/Delete records (and/or create the DB itself).  CSVs and XML are other data store alternatives, but those would require your app to include ACD editor.

Comment: Ok so if I understand right @Plutonix I can still use MS Access Databases, And use that as the container. But Use VB to populate the database. Then the data goes through the query's and does everything it normally would if they had Access?

Comment: the user does not need Access installed for your app to use an Access DB for data storage (`container`?).  They only need Access to run the Access UI (create macros, forms, queries etc).  Your app would have to provide ACD services though otherwise there is no way to enter/edit records

Comment: Alright Well I really appreciate the insight I'm going to play around with your ideas and see what I can do. The Company I made the program for does have Access already but I'm trying to make a more general version that doesn't have the same limitations.